# RecyclerView wrapped inside CoordinatorLayout not resized when keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

Activity layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/hospital_logo" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="******* ************* ********** ************"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="***************************"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here I am using `CoordinatorLayout` with `CollapsingToolbarBar` and `ViewPager`.

I have adding two fragment inside ViewPager with layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The cell of recycler_view contains EditText. When I selects EditText SoftKeyboard opens but EditText hides behind keyboard.

I have added following flags to activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I am using 23.1.1 appcompat version of RecyclerView.

When I replace `CoordinatorLayout` with `LinearLayout` `RecyclerView` is getting resize to show last element correctly. So I thinks it is the issue with Coordinator layout.

I went through following issues https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176406 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176187 but it is nor related to this bug. Let me know if I can apply some path to solve this.

Waiting for reply. Thanks.
Let me know if more details needed.

Comment: I tried hard to fix it. At the end I have created Android issue for it. I have shared my dummy project to illustrate issue. check following link for issue status: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=199043

Comment: @streamride No I am not able to fix it. l changed the design to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had a very similar issue and was able to fix it by using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with `coordinatorLayout`. However, setting `fitsSystemWindows` to `false` resolved the problem. It seems that the main culprit is the coordinatorLayout. I solved this by encapsulating the entire layout, including the `AppBarLayout`, within a `constraintLayout`.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
           </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
         //content here
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I understand that responding to this thread comes quite late, but perhaps it can be helpful for others. :)